# Tell me if i understood this line properly

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

```
function update(
        mapping(int24 => Tick.Info) storage _self,
        int24 _tick,
        int128 _liquidityDelta,
        bool _upper
    ) internal returns(bool flipped){
    ...
    flipped = (liquidityAfter == 0) != (liquidityBefore == 0);  // this line
    ...
}
```

Please tell me if i understood the line properly:
if `(liquidityAfter == 0) != (liquidityBefore == 0)` then return `flipped` as **true** or return **false**.
Is it right??

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because it apparently flipped, since the before and after should be equal 0, but if one of them is not then it will throw true

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your code snippet, it's checking for three cases:

1. a new liquidity has been initialized
2. the liquidity has been removed entirely
3. neither #1 or #2

If the case 1 or 2 happens, we are returning `flipped = true` else `flipped = false`.